# Laravel Eloquent - Select with join where column text like column text from other table

Tags: database, laravel, join, eloquent

I want to select users from my `users` table and return a boolean if they live in a city, that exists in my `cities` table in my database.

The problem is, that I can't use the ID of the city in the users table, because I get the users list from an external source.

On a normal SQL Query I would JOIN the cities table (`users.city LIKE cities.name`) and then add a column to the result with true false.

But how is this possible in Laravel eloquent where I have my Model `User` and my model `City`. Both models have the column `city` as a text.
Of course the query should be as performant as possible and I don't want for each row a separate query.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "i get the users list from an external source"? Are you getting array of their IDs?

Comment: I get: name, address, city, ... - on Insert it automatically adds the id (auto increment)

Comment: I'll be better if you setup a city_id as foreign key in user table, primary city and make relationship reference for city and user. In that way you can use User::has('city',!=,null).

Comment: @LimKeanPhang when should I do this? While Inserting the users? But then I need an extra query to get all the cities from my db to check if the user.ctiy is in my db - right?

Comment: I have did a query for joining table please review.You might need to do some adjustment @Mike_NotGuilty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
User::join('City','user.city','=','city.name')
->select(user.city,DB::raw('(CASE WHEN user.city <> NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS is_user')
  )
```

Comment: That worked nicely and I checked it with `DB::getQueryLog()`. It's only a single Query. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In you user model you can add new accessor property

```
protected $appends = ['lives_in_city'];

public function getLivesInCityAttribute(){
    $hasCity = City::where('city', 'like', $this->city)->first();
    return $hasCity? true: false;
}
```

Now your user object will have new field `lives_in_city` which will return the boolean value.

Comment: Do not perform queries in attribute mutator. Let's say he has collection of 20 users that he wants to output in a table. Simple `foreach` with `lives_in_city` will end him up with 20 extra queries.

Comment: @d3jn he doesn't have a relation between the tables